# Tracing function calls in C++ using gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, callstack

I have a system developed in C++ on Linux platform. I am doing some debugging of this system. I want to look for the complete sequence of function calls to a function. Lets assume the functions are called in the following sequence

```
function_1 -> function_2 -> function_3 -> function_4
```

If I put a break point at function_4, the execution will be holded at that point. I want to see that functions_1, function_2 and function_3 are called before function_4. If there any gdb command to trace these function calls?

Thanks,
Ankur

Comment: Does function_1 get called and then return - or does function_1 call function_2() et al

Comment: RTFM: it's something like "bt" or "st" (back trace or stack trace).

Comment: `bt` gets the backtrace, but it relies on the stack frame, so unless all those function calls are nested (1 calls 2 calls 3 calls 4), that's not going to work for you.

Answer (score 8):

You want a backtrace. The `gdb` command `bt` will show exactly what you are interested in.

Comment: bt utility is not available on the Linux server. Is that not possible to find function calls using gdb?

Comment: Also, to examine call-stack use the command "frame" or f. More info here :  http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_43.html#SEC43

Comment: Thanks buddy, bt works. This is exactly I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

bt: backtrace
http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html

Answer (score 1):

If function_1() calls function_2() which calls function_3() etc

You can set your breakpoint in function_4() and you use the command

```
where
```

To print a backtrace of the stack

Another tool that may be useful is valgrind with the callgrind tool

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this works. It is exactly similar to bt. Thanks